# How to check the password value that being sent to LDAP server by Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, ldap, tomcat7, tomcat8

I'm having an issue while tomcat authenticating to LDAP server. The error log on stderr.log shows error like this:

```
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090446, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580 ]
```

I googled and found that the error is caused due to an incorrect password. However, I am 100% sure my password under the server.xml is correct. I use the same configurations in a similar environment and it running well.

I wonder, how could I check the connectionPassword value that is sent to the ldap server?

Comment: You can use clear text LDAP (port 389) and run a network capture (filter on something like "tcp port 389") to read through LDAP transactions. Best in a development system since passwords and such will be in plain text, but I've occasionally had to do the same thing on a production system -- off hours with the server behind a firewall to prevent "real" users from accessing it.

Comment: Do you mean running something like Wireshark?

Comment: Yes, Wireshark is suitable.